# Petition for acceptance of answer to question by vanished querent

Tags: discussion

[Collection of youth short stories about aliens 1990-1994ish](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/collection-of-youth-short-stories-about-aliens-1990-1994ish?rq=1)

The highest-rated answer matches on all points. The cover is correct. The stories inside match with what the querent was looking for. Seems safe to me to go ahead and accept that answer. It gives us one more feather in our cap. :-)

Comment: I've been reading too much sci-fi today, I read your title as "**vanquished** querant"!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As covered in [this meta.se post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80321/244929) and [many others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accepted-answer+answers+feature-request), that's not on the table.

**It's okay for a nice answer to not get accepted.** Upvote it instead, but remember: neither acceptance nor upvoting means the answer's right! Upvoting indicates the community gestalt approves of the answer, while acceptance means one single citizen found that answer most useful.

Stack Exchange makes no claim to judge correctness, only popularity and usefulness. Taking answer accepting out of the hands of the *only* person who can really know if an answer was useful would fundamentally change what that mechanic means.

Please also note that our "questions answered" statistic counts questions with positive-score answers, not questions with accepted answers, for exactly this reason. Our stats reflect the community's gestalt action rather than the actions of individual citizens. There is no "feather" missing from our cap when someone doesn't accept an answer, and forcing accepts to pad our numbers wouldn't be a good idea even if it *was* being tracked.

Comment: Ah. Understood.